# Global package installation using NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, npm, composer-php, nuget

Does NuGet support global package installation like NPM and Composer? If so, how do I do that? Also, how do I reference globally installed packages in my Visual Studio projects?

Comment: [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)? For windows, if you install any nuget package, it is actually installed in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: Thank you. That answers one of the two questions. Reading the article it looks like nuget's "global" installation is not global in the sense npm and composer packages are global, in that I can't add reference to those packages in a VS project without downloading them from the Internet. Or is it so?

Comment: Yes, you have to download one package from Internet(if the package is on one online feed) if you never download it before. After you download the package in Project A, when you open a new solution with project B, if you still need that package, now you don't need to download it the second time.  But as you said, yes, for the first time, you do need to download it..

Comment: And if the `reference` you mean is call one `xx.exe` instead of reference one `xx.dll`, you can check [Martin's blog](https://dasmulli.blog/2018/01/23/exploring-global-net-core-tools/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So learning from @Lance's tips, I went ahead and checked `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` folder, and indeed it contains all the packages that I have downloaded in the past. Unfortunately though, Visual Studio (I'm using Community 2019) does not allow you to install any of these packages into a new project. The **Browse** page in NuGet Package Manager UI displays online results only from `nuget.org`.

But then I found another clue. In Visual Studio **Tools** > **Options** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Sources**, you can add custom sources. So I went ahead and added my cache folder as an alternate source.

[image]

Note that there is a separate "Machine-wide package sources" entry too that cannot be modified. I checked that folder and it contains mostly Microsoft's own packages (one exception that I found there was `NewtonSoft.json`). I have no idea how this folder is different from the nuget cache folder and how I can download a package to this folder.

So far so good. The Package Manager now shows all previously downloaded packages from cache when I select this source from the drop down (sources dropdown is in top-right corner). I can then select a package and install it from local source instead of downloading it from the Internet.

Hope this helps someone down the line.